# Consider an AI Image generation system AI IMAGe. How hard is it to remove specific images from the training dataset and all traces of the images?

Tags: training, ai-design, open-ai

Consider an AI image generation system called AI IMAGE. Suppose someone wanted to remove 100 of their photos that had been used to train AI IMAGE for a year in generating images. Would it be easy to remove all traces of the photos from the AI system?

How hard or difficult might this be? Links to academic papers or case studies on this would be great! Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.